# Google Forms - Instant Conditional branching

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am writing a survey on Google Forms (part of Google Docs), and I notice there are some scripting capabilities built in. I wanted to know if it were possible to show and hide questions immediately, based on a choice from a bullet-point list, but without using the page-break method you are meant to use for conditional branching. We have planned to have lots of fiddly choices, which would take up an excessive number of pages.

By hiding and showing various `<div></div>`, I am hoping that you can make the form update instantly. For example, you might reach the form and be presented with:

**Which is your local branch?** ( ) London, ( ) Bristol, ( ) Manchester

Depending on which one you picked, a question would instantly be un-hidden below relating to the branch you had selected, but which would not be relevant if asked about the others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like there is a way built into Google Docs Forms that would allow you to achieve the desired behaviour.

One work around would be to use Google Docs as the "database" and host the form elsewhere, this would allow you to modify the way the form is displayed and using jQuery you would be able to show/hide the questions that are applicable to your users.

For more information take a look at http://www.2webvideo.com/blog/customizing-google-docs-form-for-email-validation-with-free-jquery-script - one of the problems with this approach is that the form is no longer hosted by Google, you would need to host the html page with the form somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunantly, I don't see how this is possible.

this would require that information would be submitted, which is done at the end of the form, which also makes the entire thing submit, makeing it impossible to edit it further.

There is one data capture point, and, being at the end, it makes it impossible to do anything useful with hidden questions (they can be there, but not be edited).

This may not be the answer that you are looking for, but it is how I see it

this is community, so if I am wrong, feel free to edit my post for accuracy, Just don't put comments in it.

Comment: although teh question got a bounty for "not enough attention", he seems to be doing the same thing to his answers that was done to his question.

Comment: Not true; I have been checking regularly. Bit of a shame that no-one seems to think it is possible though.

Comment: That's because it isn't. Unless you re-write the entire engine, it won't work. You're gonna lose the bounty rep, so please give it to someone. Don't be wasteful, please

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to achieve the same thing in the past, sadly it is not entirely possible.
I was able to get this right for a booking form.

Let's say maximum number of slots is 2, once two people have booked against a slot, then the value must change to "This session is fully booked.".

I will say, while it was possible, it was not a good system. To many things could go wrong, and all due to the limitations of google forms.

As recommended above I suggest looking into free form to accomplish what you are trying to do. Google Forms should only be used for simple data capturing.

-

PS:

I was able to achieve the above using Google Sheets functions to tally totals booked.