# Google forms conditional sections

Tags: conditional-statements, google-forms

In the latest Google Forms, how can I make questions or sections conditional based on answers?

For example, in the image below, "Would you play again?", a "No" answer should reveal "If no, why not?" question:

[image]

I've searched this, but found old articles, like:

[this one from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10466666/google-forms-instant-conditional-branching) that says it's not available

[and this one, from 3 months ago](https://appsheethelp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/206435467-Multi-page-forms-with-conditional-branching) that suggests awkward page breaks to lead to a new page

I'm hoping to have questions seamlessly appear as needed.

Is this possible with Google forms?

Answer (score 0):

This question brings up the same issue as the very recent one asked at:
[How to pull data from Google Form and display result before submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36091041/how-to-pull-data-from-google-form-and-display-result-before-submission)
So the answer would still be the same.

> What you are asking for is to create dynamic data in Google Forms
>   without clicking the submit button.
>
> **This is NOT possible in Google Forms**. Please have a look at the [available
>   triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#available_types_of_triggers).
>
> Since there can be no triggers activated after the form is loaded,
>   there can be no interaction while filling and before submitting the
>   form. Not even using a script.    Having said that your other choice
>   would be to use the HtmlService or the UiServise instead and build
>   your own web app.

To conclude. Many may have changed in Google Forms since [the 2012 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10699952/1527780). Unfortunately, what you are asking for is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it's the "awkward page breaks" as you mentioned, through sections.

1. Create a section (section 1) for your "would you play again?" question.
2. Create another section underneath (section 2) with the question "why not?"
3. Create another section to continue to if they chose "yes" on section 1.
4. On section 1's "yes, no" list click the menu next to the "Required" toggle and select "go to section based on answer"
5. On "yes", select "Go to section 3"
6. On "no", select "Go to section 2"